# Unable to grant Camera permission in Android Things

Tags: android-things

I am using a Raspberry PI3 board to run Android Things dev-preview 0.5.0. A camera is attached to the board. To grant permission manually to the camera I am running following command in terminal:

*adb shell pm grant org.tensorflow.demo android.permission.CAMERA*

However I am getting following error in return:

*Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot grant system fixed permission android.permission.CAMERA for package org.tensorflow.demo*

The application is running successfully but it does not capture any image.

Comment: turning your pi off and on again will also grant the permission (at boot time)

Comment: turning the pi off and on didn't help. The issue persists.

Comment: update to AT `0.6.1`

Answer (score 2):

Rebooting RPi did not work for me.  I found that granting the permission manually resolved the access issue:

```
adb shell pm grant <your.package.name> android.permission.CAMERA
```

See [this post](https://github.com/androidthings/doorbell/issues/4) on Github

Answer (score 1):

It is a old issue, but right now works very fine, a few months ago you were need a single reboot for take a permissions, but now I don't to do. Otherwise, you can try the next code example:

*Complete code*: https://github.com/hpsaturn/bgcamera

**Manifiest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

**Check permission:**

```
    // We need permission to access the camera
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // A problem occurred auto-granting the permission
        Log.d(TAG, "No permission");
        return;
    }
```

**Init camera**

```
/**
 * Starts a builtin camera with api camera 2
 */
private void startCamera() {
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        String pickedCamera = getCamera(manager);
        manager.openCamera(pickedCamera, cameraStateCallback, null);
        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth, mHeight, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 4 /* images buffered */);
        mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(onImageAvailableListener, null);
        Log.d(TAG, "imageReader created");
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I based from original code of Doorbell example for Android Things:
https://github.com/androidthings/doorbell

Comment: Thanks but these are the exact lines that I have in my code already.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue and after installing the apk I restarted raspberry pi again. After that its working fine for me.

This happens because:-
Camera permission comes under dangerous permission list. And to get this kind of permission the device need to be booted once. Hope this clarifies the issue.

Comment: Yes, even I have noticed it myself. Do you know any reason for this?

Comment: Camera permission comes under dangerous permission list. And to get this kind of permission the device need to be booted once. Hope this clarifies the issue.

Comment: I have restarted the raspberry PI module and still the problem persists.